# Arx celebris fontibus

Tags: idiom, translation-check, translation-explanation

I bought yesterday a bottled mineral water, of the Harrogate brand, which label states:

> Harrogate's *motto* 'Arx celebris fontibus' translates as 'a citadel famous for its springs'.

(this is the *motto* of the [city of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harrogate), where the water is bottled)

That translation seems odd to me. [This article](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/1999/jan/28/martinwainwright1) suggests instead that the *motto* translates as

> Citadel of the Famous Springs

This makes much more sense. [*celebris*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/celebris#Latin) is, according to Wiktionary, the **genitive singular** of *celeber*, hence the "of the famous" bit. Maybe, the "official" translation is more accurate for something like *arx celeber quia fontibus*? Or is it still an "accurate" translation?

Comment: Don't believe google translate! "quia" means "for, because, since" (conjunction). It does not mean "for, on account of" (preposition).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Arx celebris fontibus" is correctly translated as "a citadel famous for its springs."

The form *celebris* here is feminine nominative singular, in agreement with *arx.* As a third-declension "[adjective of three terminations](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-adjectives-classification-and-paradigms)", *celeber* has a masculine nominative singular form *celeber,* a feminine nominative singular form *celebris,* and a neuter nominative singular form *celebre*. Because "arx" is a feminine noun, it's not correct to say "arx celeber".

*Celebris* is also the genitive singular form (for all genders), but here there is no genitive singular noun for it to modify. "Fontibus" is a dative/ablative plural form; we know it is not modified by the adjective because if it were, we'd see "**celebribus** fontibus". Lewis and Short notes that *[celeber](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dceleber)* can take a complement in the ablative case, which is how "celebris fontibus" means "famous for its springs".

To express "Citadel of the Famous Springs", I would expect *famous* and *springs* to both be inflected for the genitive plural, giving us something like "arx celebrium fontium".

Comment: The sad moment when you realise your learning speed is much  slower than you think.